# Bali entry requirements - what do they mean by "source countries" in this article?

Tags: covid-19, indonesia, bali

Bali is now open to some international arrivals (https://coconuts.co/bali/news/indonesia-finally-confirms-19-eligible-countries-as-bali-reopens-to-foreign-tourism-today/).

Is eligibility based on your passport country or the country you have been in for the last so many days, or what - does anyone know? My passport country is not on the list but at the point of travel I would have been in an eligible country for over a month.

The obvious place to look would be the government announcement referred to in the article, but I haven't found a link to it, and anyway I'd then be relying on Google translate.

Comment: A quick search seems to indicate that the information on the topic is still very partial, with few if any details published. The government's official page on the topic https://www.imigrasi.go.id/en/covid19-1/ has 2 sentences in english and the rest in Indonesian. The list of regulations https://www.imigrasi.go.id/en/covid19-8/ hasn't been updated since September 17th. I think you'll have to wait a bit for the actual rules to be published (though as lambshaanxy says, it is nearly always the countries you were in recently which count).

Answer (score 2):

Nearly universally, COVID "source country" restrictions are about **where you are coming from and where you have been**, not your passport.

Note that Immigration restrictions to get visas etc usually *are* based on your passport, and are cumulative to health restrictions.